# Suspend the application

Tags: iphone

How can I suspend my application or send a suspend message to my application?

I want to simulate pressing the home button.

Answer (score 36):

There is a private instance method for UIApplication:

The following code would work, (tested in an iPhone 3GS):

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app performSelector:@selector(suspend)];
```

Comment: Is this accepted by the app store? I know that for few cases exit(0) will be rejected. I'm not sure about suspend. Can you confirm me?

Comment: @Chan You should never call private API for an app you submit through the app store. See Brad's answer for best practice.

Comment: This is not to encourage you to use a private API but I have apps already in the app store with this. Although while submitting it on the app store it displays a warning that there is a private API used.

Comment: If it is private you can't. Never use any private apis inside any productive apps, it could break your neck!

Comment: Does this still work?  We want to use it only in some Unit Tests (not in App Store) to test some background handling logic.  Running this (using the Swift version down below) and after running it the applicationState is still active.   Before I spend too much time figuring out why, I wanted to see if others have been successfully using this in 2022.

Answer (score 25):

In swift:

```
let application = UIApplication.shared
let suspend = #selector(URLSessionTask.suspend)
application.sendAction(suspend, to: application, from: nil, for: nil)
```

Comment: Works! is there a way to resume it programmatically once suspended?

Comment: I think that no

Comment: Do you guys know how to implement this scenario in Xamarin, please?

Answer (score 17):

Quitting your application or sending it to the background programmatically is a violation of the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27), which usually doesn't bode well for getting through the review process:

> **Don’t Quit Programmatically**
>
> Never quit an iOS application
>   programmatically because people tend
>   to interpret this as a crash. However,
>   if external circumstances prevent your
>   application from functioning as
>   intended, you need to tell your users
>   about the situation and explain what
>   they can do about it. Depending on how
>   severe the application malfunction is,
>   you have two choices.
>
> **Display an attractive screen that describes the problem and suggests a
>   correction.** A screen provides
>   feedback that reassures users that
>   there’s nothing wrong with your
>   application. It puts users in control,
>   letting them decide whether they want
>   to take corrective action and continue
>   using your application or press the
>   Home button and open a different
>   application
>
> **If only some of your application's features are not working, display
>   either a screen or an alert when
>   people activate the feature.** Display
>   the alert only when people try to
>   access the feature that isn’t
>   functioning.

The philosophical reason for this is explained earlier in that document:

> People, not applications, should
>   initiate and control actions. Although
>   an application can suggest a course of
>   action or warn about dangerous
>   consequences, it’s usually a mistake
>   for the app to take decision-making
>   away from the user. The best apps find
>   the correct balance between giving
>   people the capabilities they need
>   while helping them avoid dangerous
>   outcomes.
>
> Users feel more in control of an app
>   when behaviors and controls are
>   familiar and predictable. And, when
>   actions are simple and
>   straightforward, users can easily
>   understand and remember them.
>
> People expect to have ample
>   opportunity to cancel an operation
>   before it begins, and they expect to
>   get a chance to confirm their
>   intention to perform a potentially
>   destructive action. Finally, people
>   expect to be able to gracefully stop
>   an operation that’s underway.

There should be no reason that you need to force your application into the background during its operation.  It should remain fully functional when displayed onscreen and it should be up to the user when they want to switch away from your application.

Comment: will you say the right, but the application initiates a notify, and should reopen 
close and you know what is happening is open only to perform some 
instructions, thanks anyway!

Comment: @BradLarson What if you create a back/exit button that closes the app? You're still giving the user a choice to exit in that case. Also, I disagree with being discouraged from using exit() because the home button could stop working after being overused for a long time, and in that case, how would a user exit back to the home screen?

Comment: Is there any chance that i can suspend my iOS application to test a specific use case? I can use private API's because i will be using this in testing and development only. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.

If you want to exit your app, don't fear rejection and love false positive crash report emails from users you could call `exit(0);`

Comment: Using `exit(0)` will terminate the app and not suspend it (e.g. move it to the background).

Answer (score -7):

**Use :**

```
 sleep(15)
```

it will suspend your app for specific time

Comment: This will freeze the app for a specific amount of time (if done on the main queue), which is not the same as suspending it (e.g. moving it to the background).

Comment: add if you use sleep for longer than 10sec on main thread, OS will kill your app.

Answer (score -9):

When the application is suspended, a `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification is posted.

I would guess you could try to post this notification manually. Didn't try this myself though.

Comment: The notification is raised by iOS and calling the method yourself will not suspend the app.

Comment: Also, this notification is sent when the app is becoming "inactive", not when it is becoming "suspended". Very different things. AFAIK there is no notification whatsoever when an app  becomes suspended.