# Suspend ios application running in background

Tags: ios, multitasking

I'm writing an app that sometimes needs to run in background ( something like a navigator, if navigation is active it should go on while if it's not it should be suspended ); how can I force force the application state after user clicks home ? ( suspended or executing in background )

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
exit(0);
```

At the application delegate state, either the background one, the foreground or whichever is most suitable for your case.

Comment: ok, but this crashes the app, i wanted to simply suspends it.

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360846/suspend-the-application