# Can I redirect to launcher screen from iOs App?

Tags: ios, swift

I am a newbee in iOS app development, and trying to create a small app using Xcode. One of my views has button to close the app. When a user taps this button, then I have to redirect the user to the "launch screen".

But don't know how. Can anybody guide me?

Thanks

Comment: If you close your app on a button action then apple may reject your app.
Launcher screen i.e. appears only at 1st but if you want to show it some other time then you need to use a separate view.

Comment: @ReshmiMajumder, What do you mean by "App. Launcher Screen". I am looking for a device Launcher Screen, not for a "splash screen". Thanks

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Is there any way to programatically send my iPhone app to the background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989030/is-there-any-way-to-programatically-send-my-iphone-app-to-the-background)

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no way you can 'close' an app programmatically. The alternative solution is to force crash the app using the `exit` function.

you can use the code below:

```
exit(0);
```

Comment: thanks for reply. If I do exit(0), What is the drawback? Is it proper way to do this? Does it effect any user experience or any negative impact?

Comment: No there is no issue with using this line. you can use it. Even I have used it in one of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Apple strongly discourages you to programmatically quit an iOS application. The standard way to move back to (redirect to) the Launcher screen (which by the way is Home screen for iOS) is when the user presses the Home button.

Calling `exit(0)`, will not invoke the **UIApplicationDelegate** methods such as `applicationWillTerminate:` etc., and thus should not be used in general.

Reference of the Same can be found in Apple's [Technical Q&A QA1561](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html)