# Go back to Safari after completing task in iOS App Clip

Tags: ios, apple-appclips

I am writing an App Clip that [is invoked](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/configuring_the_launch_experience_of_your_app_clip) [from Safari](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/associating_your_app_clip_with_your_website).

After the user starts the app clip from Safari and completes the task in the app clip, how do I close the app clip and go back to Safari? Do I just tell the user that "you're done, go back to Safari" or can I do it for them? Apparently just doing `exit(0)` in an app [will not pass review for the App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989030/is-there-any-way-to-programmatically-send-my-iphone-app-to-the-background).

Comment: did you resolved it ?

Comment: Basically, I want to open appClip using safari, just like custom URL Scheme, means by rithing the custom URL Scheme or associated domain in safari and open app clip, is it possible in the development/iphone?, or I need a domain before invoke appClip ?

Comment: No, I didn't find a way to do it. During development you can set the opening app clip URL by [setting the `_XCAppClipURL` variable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/testing_the_launch_experience_of_your_app_clip).