# How to open a URL in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

`openURL` has been deprecated in Swift 3.

Can anyone provide some examples of how the replacement `openURL:options:completionHandler:` works when trying to open a url?

Answer (score 416, accepted):

All you need is:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com") else {
  return //be safe
}

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: what if i use '+' operator in my url ? For example: "https://xxxxx.com./xxxxxxxxxxxxxx="+userName+"xxxxxxx="+userPass+"&xxxxxxxxx"  like this.  That string given me an error "No '+' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'URL"

Comment: you have to use the + operator on your `String` instead on the `URL`

Comment: Side Note:  don't try to do this:  UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "insert url here")!).   The compiler on XCode 8 will get confused and not be able to build properly.  So just use this solution as is.  Works great!  Thanks.

Comment: How would I open the url without actually opening Safari? How do I get the url to "open" in the background? Please answer my question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686252/swift-3-and-json-updating-the-database-by-running-a-url-in-the-background.

Comment: You mean Swift doesn't make you climb walls to do something as complex as opening a URL? [jaw dropped]

Comment: it was killing me that options: [:] is required but options: nil won't compile

Answer (score 44):

Above answer is correct but if you want to check you `canOpenUrl` or not try like this.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.facebook.com")!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    //If you want handle the completion block than 
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
         print("Open url : \(success)")
    })
}
```

**Note:** If you do not want to handle completion you can also write like this.

```
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
```

No need to write `completionHandler` as it contains default value `nil`, check [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open) for more detail.

Answer (score 39):

If you want to open inside the app itself instead of leaving the app you can **import SafariServices** and work it out.

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url!)
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This method is the best practice according the iOS guidelines

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3** version

```
import UIKit

protocol PhoneCalling {
    func call(phoneNumber: String)
}

extension PhoneCalling {
    func call(phoneNumber: String) {
        let cleanNumber = phoneNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
        guard let number = URL(string: "telprompt://" + cleanNumber) else { return }

        UIApplication.shared.open(number, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use a regular expression with `replacingOccurrences`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using macOS Sierra (v10.12.1) Xcode v8.1 Swift 3.0.1 and here's what worked for me in ViewController.swift:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  UIWebViewExample
//
//  Created by Scott Maretick on 1/2/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Scott Maretick. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //added this code
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Your webView code goes here
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            //If you want handle the completion block than
            UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
                print("Open url : \(success)")
            })
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


};
```