# open "Messages" app in my app

Tags: ios, url, swift3

I'm trying to develop an app, that take a number from a variable then open in "Messages" app with (1500) in the field To: and the variable value in Text Messages field [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xJ8f.png)
I tried this answer [how to open an URL in Swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546856/how-to-open-an-url-in-swift3) and [Swift: How to open a new app when uibutton is tapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932303/swift-how-to-open-a-new-app-when-uibutton-is-tapped) but i didn't figure out the URL for Messages app

what should I use? Big thanks.

Comment: Consider using `MFMessageComposeViewController` instead of launching the Messages app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() == true{
        let recipients:[String] = ["1500"]
        var messageController = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        //messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self // implement delegate if you want
        messageController.recipients = recipients
        messageController.body = "Your_text"
        self.present(messageController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: thank you, it was really helpful. but for some reason it didn't appear, I implement delegate and import `MessageUI` with no errors but still not appear after clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import "MessageUI" to your class and use the below code.

```
func sendMessages() {   
    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() == true {
        let recipients:[String] = ["9895249619"]
        let messageController = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        messageController.messageComposeDelegate  = self
        messageController.recipients = recipients
        messageController.body = "Your_message_text"
        self.present(messageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        //handle text messaging not available
    }
}

func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {    
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```