# Phone call button in Swift 3 doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

I need my app make a phone call when user taps a button. I found some tutorials and people there say use this code

```
let numberUrl = URL(string: "tel://12345678")!
UIApplication.shared.open(numberUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

But it just does not work. Was it change in Swift 3?

Comment: Are you testing that on the simulator?

Comment: `tel` URLs don't have slashes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to open an URL in Swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546856/how-to-open-an-url-in-swift3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Try this code for Call.
Code Works for all iOS versions

**Swift 2.0**

```
 let url = URL(string: "tel://123456789")!
 UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
 let url = URL(string: "tel://123456789")!
 UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

Comment: No its working fine for me even not display warning for deprecated.

Comment: No its not deprecated. cmd+click on open(url), it will navigate to documentation, there it shows its available in ios10

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, you want to deal with the deprecation warning.

```
if #available(iOS 10, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(numberUrl)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(numberUrl)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way in your real device, simulator doesn't place a call.

```
let phoneUrl = "tel://45657657" //your url
      if let url = URL(string: phoneUrl){
           if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
              UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
            } else {
              // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
       }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this...**

```
let url:URL = URL(string: "tel:\(phone_number)")!
    let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
    if (application.canOpenURL(url)) {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            application.open(url)
        } else {
            application.openURL(url)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, check the condition that checks for if application can open url or not

Comment: Please stop upvoting each other's stuff. And please only post useful answers. That's all I'm saying. Be honest, be fair, and post good content that has not already been posted a thousand times.

Comment: Yes, @KiranSarvaiya. You and Rishu should flag as duplicate *instead* of posting the same stuff again.