# Swift: how to open the URL in inner browser in the App, not in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift

how I can open url in **native inner browser** in app, like this

> *Attention: this is not UIWebView*

[image: inner browser]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to open an URL in Swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546856/how-to-open-an-url-in-swift3)

Comment: `WKWebView` is the component you are looking for?

Comment: user Web view in your application.

Comment: I think you want SFSafariViewController, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller?language=objc

Comment: guys this is not a webview, and thanks @Leo, you save me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try this code for swift, you can open default browser (Safari) in your APP using below code**

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url!)
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```