# How to open another app with passing parameters on Background?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, mobile

I'm developing two different iOS apps. I would like to open and transmit data to second app on background? I don't want to open second app with UI. How can I overcome to this problem?

Comment: Define 2 url scheme for your apps. Then open url with parameter you need to send from one app to the other

Comment: I added url schemes for the apps but it opens with UI. How can I do it on background?

Comment: You can find some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546856/how-to-open-an-url-in-swift3)  . Just put your own url scheme and parameters for url parameter.

Comment: I looked it up, but I didn't see any information about opening another app on background mode.

Comment: The open url can reactivate an app which is in background