# Button that works like home button on iPhone

Tags: swift, xcode9.3

Is there any way to create a button in Swift that acts in the same way as the iPhone home button? I am looking for a way to do this, whether programmatically or by using Xcode's drag and drop feature for adding buttons.

Comment: Don’t do this. The phone already has a home button. It doesn’t need another one. You really really shouldn’t be quitting the app yourself. Even from a button press. Let Apple deal with the running and quitting/suspending of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next line of code worked for me (Swift 4):

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIControl().sendAction(#selector(NSXPCConnection.suspend), to: UIApplication.shared, for: nil)
}
```

**Edit:**

As @martin-r says, I took this code from SO some months ago from here: 
[stackoverflow.com/a/46512619/1187415](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46512619/1187415)

Comment: This looks like a copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46512619/1187415, without attribution.

Comment: Indeed it is, I found it some months ago and forgot that it was at SO